# Spring source suite spring3 + Hibernate4 + maven 3 + MySQL 5

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting an error in my application but I'm not sure what it means. I posted some sample code bellow. This is the error I get:

```
> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
> instance of class
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to
> requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
> org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to
> requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]     at
> org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.unwrap(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:91)
>   at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.java:101)
>   at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:264)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
>   ... 22 more
> 
> ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context
> initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to
> requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
> org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to
> requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]     at
> org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.unwrap(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:91)
>   at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.java:101)
>   at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:264)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
>   ... 22 more
```

This is my pom file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.reservosity</groupId>
<artifactId>component</artifactId>
<name>Reservosity</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The servet-context:

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.reservosity.component.controller" />
```

The root-context.xml:

```
<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

The hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/******</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">***</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">***</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <mapping class="com.company.component.domain.Company" />
</session-factory>
```

If I remove the bean transactionManager, it works fine, but when I add it in again, I get that dirty looking error. Not sure why.

```
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

I am new to spring hibernate and could really do with some help!

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Did u manage to fix this issue? i am having the exact same problem

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've exactly the same problem. KyelJmD suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670840/error-creating-bean-with-name-when-creating-a-transaction-manager) that there is a missing connection pooling, and it seems he is right, but he didn't post solution.

So I've spent some time and finaly get it working. To solve this problem you should do two things:

1. add these lines into hibernate.cfg.xml file (it's possible that you don't need all of it):

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
   ```
2. Add this dependencies in pom.xml:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Without maven dependency Hibernate just silently ignores C3P0 configuration.

With above configuration I dont't get anymore UnknownUnwrapTypeException exception, and it seems it works fine now.

My setup: Spring 3.2.1, Hibernate 4.1.9, Tomcat 7.0.35.

Dislaimer: as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653591/why-configure-both-datasource-and-sessionfactory-in-spring-hibernate-configurati) question, you should rather not use hibernate.cfg.xml file. Use `dataSource` bean instead, because, for example, you can use it later for JdbcTemplate.

**EDIT :**

It's been a while, as I answered this question. It seemed correct, but I never like it, because it was kind of guess, which we should really avoid.

So, because I found this interresting and I was unable to find anything in Hibernate 4.1 docs, I tried to proof my and other commenters "guess".

Here is a step-by-step procedure, probably also useful for solving other weird issues in other libraries. 
Turns out this time it was really easy, what is going on.

1. Create a Maven Project (or use existing one), add Hibernate to dependency (hibernate-entitymanager, I used this time version 4.1.7). Import it into IDE which can automatically attach source code (I used Intellij)
2. From Stack Trace, find the class where exception (`UnknownUnwrapTypeException`) has been thrown (`DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl`) and navigate there (CTRL-N and type class name), click "Download sources".
3. Find usages of `DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl` (ALT+F7)
4. Voila! Turns out there is only one usage of `DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl` - it is a `initiateService(...)` method in `ConnectionProviderInitiator`, which  - more or less - tries a couple `ConnectionProvider` implementations, before it fallbacks to `DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl`, which in our case doesn't work and throws `UnknownUnwrapTypeException`.

From Hibernate's ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:

```
        ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = null;
    String providerClassName = getConfiguredConnectionProviderName( configurationValues );
    if ( providerClassName != null ) {
        connectionProvider = instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider( providerClassName, classLoaderService );
    }
    else if ( configurationValues.get( Environment.DATASOURCE ) != null ) {
        connectionProvider = new DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl();
    }

    if ( connectionProvider == null ) {
        if ( c3p0ConfigDefined( configurationValues ) && c3p0ProviderPresent( classLoaderService ) ) {
            connectionProvider = instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider( C3P0_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME,
                    classLoaderService
            );
        }
    }

    if ( connectionProvider == null ) {
        if ( proxoolConfigDefined( configurationValues ) && proxoolProviderPresent( classLoaderService ) ) {
            connectionProvider = instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider( PROXOOL_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME,
                    classLoaderService
            );
        }
    }

    if ( connectionProvider == null ) {
        if ( configurationValues.get( Environment.URL ) != null ) {
            connectionProvider = new DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl();
        }
    }

    if ( connectionProvider == null ) {
        LOG.noAppropriateConnectionProvider();
        connectionProvider = new UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl();
    }
```

The code roughly shows that:

1. If `Environment.DATASOURCE` (hibernate.connection.datasource) is set, then `DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl` is used;
2. If there is c3p0 present, then C3P0 Provider is instantiated
3. Some other provider is checked (PROXOOL_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME)
4. Then if `Environment.URL` (hibernate.connection.url) is present, we use `DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl`.

And that's it. This explains why if we add C3P0 as Maven Dependency or define DataSource (as [Michael ako Tecourt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2187110/michael-ako-tecourt) says in comment below) solves the issue.

Another matter is why DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl throws UnknownUnwrapTypeException - wheather it is a bug or not - anyway, I don't see any changes in code in Hibernate 4.2.0 and even 4.3.0.Beta.

Comment: I use Spring 3.2 Hibernate 4 on my project with @Configuraton instead of XML, and this was a great help.

Comment: Precision : I just found out that you don't really need C3P0... in reality, it looks like a bug. When you start defining hibernate properties (like "dialect" and such) you need to explicitely define c3p0 related properties, but if you just define a datasource and entity classes everything works perfectly !!

Comment: +1 Incredible how people find these solutions on their own ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the issue it's coming from this code:

```
if ( ConnectionProvider.class.equals( unwrapType ) ||
                DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.class.isAssignableFrom( unwrapType ) ) {
            return (T) this;
        }
        else {
            throw new UnknownUnwrapTypeException( unwrapType );
        }
```

where unwrapType is `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Whilst I can't explain exactly what it is about your config that causes this I can suggest a fix.

Define a `DriverManagerDataSource` bean in your spring application context and then provide this as a property to your `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. Make sure you remove the datasource configuration from your Hibernate configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

try include spring and hibernate library to lib folder to your project. I hope these helps.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.coderanch.com/t/581183/Spring/Spring-Hibernate-transaction-Management-Cannot) suggests that you don't have a datasource defined in your hibernate config file.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but i already had a datasource in my hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 0):

This article has detailed instruction on Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.1 integration:

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/