# Why configure both dataSource and sessionFactory in Spring-Hibernate Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring 3.1.2 and Hibernate 4.1.7 for my web application. I want to now configure both of these. I have my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <!-- 
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
         -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>       
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My `webapp-servlet.xml` spring config file:

```
<beans>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>
            classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<bean id = "dataSource" class = "org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name = "username" value = "root" />
    <property name = "password" value = "root" />
    <property name = "maxActive" value = "10" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

1. Why do I need to configure a DataSource bean when all of the data needed is already included in the hibernate configuration file? Does Hibernate have some default it can use?
2. What are some other `DataSource`s I can use?
3. Am I missing any other beans or configuration parameters/properties to get hibernate working with my application?

Comment: All configuration options from your `hibernate.cfg.xml` are available on `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, prefer the latter and skip them in Hibernate configuration.

Comment: Ok. But I still only want them in a single place, not repeated in different files or beans.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, remove data source configuration from `hibernate.cfg.xml` and leave it in Spring XML. You can later use the same `dataSource` bean e.g. in `JdbcTemplate`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You don't need both of them. You can either get rid of `hibernate.cfg.xml` and configure everything in `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, or reuse your existing `hibernate.cfg.xml` as is (in this case you don't need to configure `DataSource` in Spring config).
2. You have the following options:

   - Use [embedded database](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support) - it's good for testing and learning purposes
   - Use `DriverManagerDataSource` - it's a simple non-pooled datasource that can be used for testing, etc (not recommended for production use)
   - Use connection pool such as DBCP or c3p0
   - If you deploy to application server you can use connection pool provided by the application server [using JNDI](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee-jndi-lookup)
3. Your current configuration is sufficient, but it lacks support of [Spring transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html). In order to enable it you need to

   - Declare `HibernateTransactionManager`
   - Add `<tx:annotation-driven>` to enable declarative transaction management (`@Transactional`)
   - Declare `TransactionTemplate` if you want to use programmatic transaction management (use it to overcome limitations of declarative transaction management)
   - Also don't forget to remove transaction-related properties from Hibernate configuration since they may conflict with Spring transaction management

Comment: Doesn't Hibernate use C3P0 by default? Thanks for the transaction management, I was looking for that as well. Accepted as full answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: If you configure it using `hibernate.cfg.xml` - yes. But Spring decouples Hibernate configuration from `DataSource` configuration, therefore you can use different `DataSource` implementations.