# Error when trying to create transactionManager bean in a Spring - Hibernate application

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am getting an error from spring when it tries to create a transaction manager bean.
I am posting my java classes and configuration files below.

foo.bar/HelloApp.java :

```
package foo.bar;

import com.mkyong.stock.bo.StockBo;
import com.mkyong.stock.model.StockEntity;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class HelloApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

        StockBo stockBo = (StockBo)context.getBean("stockBo");

        //insert
        StockEntity stock = new StockEntity();
        stock.setStockCode("7668");
        stock.setStockName("HAIO");
        stockBo.save(stock);

        //select
        StockEntity stock2 = stockBo.findByStockCode("7668");
        System.out.println(stock2);

        //update
        //stock2.setStockName("HAIO-1");
        //stockBo.update(stock2);

        //delete
        //stockBo.delete(stock2);

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

com.mkyong.stock.bo/StockBoImpl.java :

```
package com.mkyong.stock.bo;

import com.mkyong.stock.dao.StockDao;
import com.mkyong.stock.model.StockEntity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("stockBo")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public class StockBoImpl implements StockBo{

    @Autowired
    StockDao stockDao;

    public void setStockDao(StockDao stockDao)
    {
        this.stockDao = stockDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(StockEntity stock) {
        stockDao.save(stock);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(StockEntity stock) {
        stockDao.save(stock);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(StockEntity stock) {
        stockDao.delete(stock);
    }

    @Override
    public StockEntity findByStockCode(String stockCode) {
        return stockDao.findByStockCode(stockCode);
    }
}
```

com.mkyong.stock.dao/StockDaoImpl.java :

```
package com.mkyong.stock.dao;

import com.mkyong.stock.model.StockEntity;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository("stockDao")
public class StockDaoImpl implements StockDao{

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StockDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    private Session currentSession()
    {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(StockEntity stock) {
        currentSession().save(stock);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(StockEntity stock) {
        currentSession().update(stock);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(StockEntity stock) {
        currentSession().delete(stock);
    }

    @Override
    public StockEntity findByStockCode(String stockCode) {
        return (StockEntity)currentSession().get(StockEntity.class, stockCode);
    }
}
```

com.mkyong.stock.model/StockEntity.java :

```
package com.mkyong.stock.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;


@javax.persistence.Table(name = "stock", schema = "", catalog = "mkyong",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_NAME"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_CODE")
        }
)
@Entity
public class StockEntity implements Serializable{
    private int stockId;
    private String stockCode;
    private String stockName;

    //---constructors
    public StockEntity() {
    }

    public StockEntity(String stockCode, String stockName) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    //---getters and setters
    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 10, precision = 0)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    public int getStockId() {
        return stockId;
    }

    public void setStockId(int stockId) {
        this.stockId = stockId;
    }



    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 10, precision = 0)
    @Basic
    public String getStockCode() {
        return stockCode;
    }

    public void setStockCode(String stockCode) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
    }



    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "STOCK_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 20, precision = 0)
    @Basic
    public String getStockName() {
        return stockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        StockEntity that = (StockEntity) o;

        if (stockId != that.stockId) return false;
        if (stockCode != null ? !stockCode.equals(that.stockCode) : that.stockCode != null) return false;
        if (stockName != null ? !stockName.equals(that.stockName) : that.stockName != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = stockId;
        result = 31 * result + (stockCode != null ? stockCode.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (stockName != null ? stockName.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Stock [stockCode=" + stockCode + ", stockId=" + stockId + ", stockName=" + stockName + "]";
    }
}
```

resources/hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyong</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mypassword</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <mapping class="com.mkyong.stock.model.StockEntity"/>
        <mapping resource="mapping.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

resources/spring-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar, com.mkyong.stock"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

And here is the error stack trace I get :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at foo.bar.HelloApp.main(HelloApp.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.unwrap(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:85)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.java:91)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Does the answer from [“Error creating bean with name” When creating a Transaction Manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670840/error-creating-bean-with-name-when-creating-a-transaction-manager) help?

Comment: I have already searched stackoverflow and even googled it before I post my question.

Comment: The main issue should be this: Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource].       What is your db config?

Comment: @martin-frey : look at resources/hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Does this thread help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691486/spring-source-suite-spring3-hibernate4-maven-3-mysql-5

Answer (score 2):

What is standing out to me on first sight are the properties you set. From what I know Hibernate expects to find the connection properties you specified in the hibernate properties. (see the following from http://docs.huihoo.com/hibernate/hibernate-reference-2.1.7/session-configuration.html)

```
 Hibernate will obtain (and pool) connections using java.sql.DriverManager if you set the following properties:

Table 3.1. Hibernate JDBC Properties
Property name   Purpose
hibernate.connection.driver_class   jdbc driver class
hibernate.connection.url    jdbc URL
hibernate.connection.username   database user
hibernate.connection.password   database user password
hibernate.connection.pool_size  maximum number of pooled connections
```

In your case this means replacing:

```
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyong</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mypassword</property>
```

With (which is how it is shown on mykong):

```
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyong</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mypassword</property>
```

Another possible way would be to specify a JDBC DataSource been and injecting it to into the SessionFactory, like this for example:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://<Host>:<Port>;databaseName=<DBName>;" />
        <property name="username" value=<username> />
        <property name="password" value=<password> />
   </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
......
```